# Validate form with more links

Tags: php, html

How I can to do to validate a form contains more links( < a href >) and this when clicked

Comment: Just forgot what are you thinking and read the question. Did you get this? No you did not get this explain buddy

Comment: What do you mean with validate?

Comment: I want to send HTTP POST parameters, I have many links on different pages but the parameters to send are the same, so I wanted to go through a form and put in the form of internal links by clicking on a Links to validate the form and will redirect the page at which point the url

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
        <form name="form" method="post" action="#">
          <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="val" />
          <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="va2" />
          <input type="hidden" name="name3" value="va3" />
          <a href="url-1"  >Link 1 </a>
          <a href="url-2"  >Link 2 </a>
          <a href="url-3"  >Link 3 </a>
          <a href="url-4"  >Link 4 </a>
        </form>
```

Comment: wait, you want to send this form to the link's address or what? So if you click **Link 1**, form sends data to **url-1**. or, I did not get it right?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, perhaps by stating more comprehensively what it is you intend on achieving, what you have so far, and what you have tried. Also, please edit your question rather than posting answers to supplement it.

Comment: Btw, you can't validate post-data just using HTML (Ajax can do it for example or some JavaScript code to do client-side validation) but you can send your POST request to separate PHP script, do validation, and then redirect to the specific link if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need **validateform.php** script to do validation of post data. Then just use `$_POST['redirecturl']` to redirect user. I'm not just experienced with this kind of coding but guess something like this is what you want (if i got your confusing question right).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function PostAndRedirect(url) {
  document.getElementById('redurl').value=url
  }
-->
</script>

<form name="form" method="post" action="validateform.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="val" />
  <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="va2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="name3" value="va3" />
  <input type="hidden" id="redurl" name="redirecturl" value="none" />
  <a href="javascript:PostAndRedirect('url-1')"  >Link 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:PostAndRedirect('url-2')"  >Link 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:PostAndRedirect('url-3')"  >Link 3</a>
  <a href="javascript:PostAndRedirect('url-4')"  >Link 4</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```